# How to check if a user is returning back from a new URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

My scenario is like that:

I have a web application. Once I log in to my application I go to URL and type some new URL say "Google.com" just after that I am clicking on back button.

- What is happening: I am able to come back to my web page as logged in user.
- What should be: Session should be invalid and user should again log in .

**How can I know whether the user have moved to some new URL and returning back.**

Thanks

Comment: This is normal behavior. The session is the same across all tabs and windows. What if the user goes to another page using another tab? Why not use a session timeout and if no activity for specified time, then logout? This seems to me like an anti-pattern, like disabling right-click. Anyway, this is js in plain sight, no security guaranteed.

Comment: Time out is ok. but for that I need to wait for some specific time. my case is different. if user moved to any new URL and returning back to my web application immediately I should also invalidate my session.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `beforeunload` event and if it is fired, send a request to log the user out in combination with a check for the referer given in `document.referrer`:

```
   if(typeof window.addEventListener !== 'undefined')
   {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
         // logout
      }, false);
   // IE support
   }
   else if(typeof window.attachEvent !== 'undefined')
   {
      window.attachEvent('beforeunload', function() {
         // logout
      });
   }
   else
   {
      window.onunload = logout();
   }
```

Comment: This does not seem as a very reliable way. What tells us that it has been sent?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. but this answer does not solved my problem. let me clarify my question by an example. suppose you have open a web page say www.abc.com and logged in to that. just after that you open another web page say www.xyz.com into same browser's tab. now if you press back button you will come to www.abc.com. but in my case after returning to www.abc.com user seems logged in, but user should again prompted for password to log in and his session should be invalidated. How can I achieve this. I am using Spring MVC.

Comment: Yes you must write the `logout()` function also where I commented `// logout` to actually log the user out! This code says "if the page is unloaded, e.g. in case he leaves the page, run code `logout`

Answer (score 0):

By using spring MCV WebContentInterceptor I am able to solve my problem upto some extends .

Answer (score -1):

Please do the following:

Check the **HTTP REFERER** for the page.
If the **HTTP REFERER** is from your own domain, then no issue.
IF the **HTTP REFERER** is from different domain then logout the user (destroy session)

I hope this would help..

Comment: Does this always work? AFAIK Chrome caches pages, so if you go back it loads it from cache instead of requesting it again.

Comment: in that case the REFERER would be null. so can act accordingly.. this is not fair enough to de-mark the answer.

Comment: I didn't though, so that user can explain his own decision.